# Difference between the following snippets. How my input stream read cycles got reduced?

Tags: java, class, buffer, inputstream, bufferedinputstream

I have my extended input stream which is like

**FIRST TRAIL**

```
public class DataReadInputStream extends java.io.InputStream{

private InputStream in = null;
public DataReadInputStream(boolean decompress) {
 initInputStream();
}
//Contains other read methods from which are in InputStream

public int read(byte[] arr, int offset, int length) {
 return this.in.read(arr, offset, length);
}

public void initInputStream(boolean decompress) {
//this.in contains some input stream value
this.in = decompress ? new GZIPInputStream(this.in) : this.in;
// NOTE: GZIPInputStream reads only 512 bytes at a time since the default buffer size in GZIPInputStream is 512
}

}
```

Now when reading a file content with my `DataReadInputStream` wrapped within `BufferedInputStream` like the following

```
ins = new DataReadInputStream(true);
bis = new BufferedInputStream(ins);
servletOutStream = res.getOutputStream();

int c = 0;
int len = 4096;
byte bufr[] = new byte[len];
while ((c = bis.read(bufr, 0, len)) != -1) {
    servletOutStream.write(bufr, 0, c);
}
```

Note: I'm wrapping my `DataReadInputStream` within `BufferedInputStream` to reduce the number of read calls (ie; BufferedInputStream fills the buffer till it can hold - which reduces the number of system calls) but it reads only 512 bytes at a time - here I could see no purpose of wrapping my `DataReadInputStream` within `BufferedInputStream`

**SECOND TRIAL**

I'm trying to achieve the same like,

```
public class DataReadInputStream extends java.io.InputStream{

public BufferedInputStream in = null;
public DataReadInputStream(boolean decompress) {
 initInputStream();
}
//Contains other read methods from which are in InputStream

public int read(byte[] arr, int offset, int length) {
 return this.in.read(arr, offset, length);
}

public void initInputStream(boolean decompress) {
InputStream ins = decompress ? new GZIPInputStream(this.in) : this.in;
this.in = new BufferedInputStream(ins);
}

}
```

Now when I try to read the file content with this `DataReadInputStream` i could read 4096 bytes at a time either with both i) and ii) (which I have given as my buffer size here)

i)

```
ins = new DataReadInputStream(true);
bis = new BufferedInputStream(ins);
servletOutStream = res.getOutputStream();

int c = 0;
int len = 4096;
byte bufr[] = new byte[len];
while ((c = bis.read(bufr, 0, len)) != -1) {
    servletOutStream.write(bufr, 0, c);
}
```

ii)

```
 ins = new DataReadInputStream(true);
 servletOutStream = res.getOutputStream();

 int c = 0;
 int len = 4096;
 byte bufr[] = new byte[len];
 while ((c = ins.read(bufr, 0, len)) != -1) {
   servletOutStream.write(bufr, 0, c);
 }
```

With **SECOND TRIAL** the number of read cycles got reduces which significantly improves the file download speed how?

Any advice in this regard is greatly appreciated ! Thanks :-)

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but some good advice: `public InputStream in = null;` should be `private` and doesn't need to be initialized to `null` twice. Consider making it `final`.  `int BUF_LEN = 4096;` should only be named in upper-case with underscores if it's `final`. Never call an overridable method from a constructor! Why is everything `public`? How does the stream get closed?

Comment: @LewBloch Thanks for pointing out.. `How does the stream get closed?` - I haven't added the full code - just added the snippet to understand the problem much better..

Comment: And the other points?

Comment: Have made the input stream private @LewBloch..

Comment: `BUF_LEN ` should be assigned as final variable... Since I don't provide the entire class here - I have just added it as a variable..

Comment: And spelled it like a `final` variable without declaring it as such.

Comment: Ok I've made the changes :-)

Answer (score -1):

Your first approach uses a `BufferedInputStream` then intentionally defeats the buffering by using custom buffering and a low-level `read` call. Thus you got all of the overhead and none of the advantage.